# Copy files based on content

Tags: bash, shell

Need to find all files in specific subdirectories ending in `.xml`. They'll either be in `.../etc/apps/<dirname>/local/data/ui/views/*.xml` or `.../etc/apps/<dirname>/default/data/ui/views/*.xml`.
If the file in `/etc/apps/<dirname>/default/data/ui/views/*.xml` doesn't have the string `version="1.1"` in the first line, copy the file to the local directory as the same file name, add that string to the first line and quit.

I'm stuck on copying the file from its default dir to its local dir.
I've got:

```bash
src=.../etc/apps/*/default/data/ui/views/*.xml
dest=.../etc/apps/*/local/data/ui/views/
pat='version='
for file in $src
do
    if [[ "$(sed -n '1{/version=/p};q' "$file")" ]]; then
        awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}' "$file"
        echo "No change necessary to $file"
    else
        echo "Copying $file to local ../local/data/ui/views/$file and running sed '1 s/>/ version="1.1">/'"
    fi
done
```

Which won't work because it's going to use the whole path for $file like I told it to.
I get the feeling I'm overthinking this. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What is the correct path for `src`? What's the `*` globe doing in that path?

Comment: That's a wildcard that works for whatever directories are in the apps dir. so apps/dir1/default, apps/dir2/default. The same for local, I want the files to be copied to apps/dir1/local/... and apps/dir2/local/...

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks:

- Instead of copy/modify the file, generating a new one in the local directory will be more efficient.
- `awk` can test the first line, print it, and even modify it, all at the same time.

Here's an idea of what you could do:

<sub>**edit:** handling the glob in the path and the possible pre-existence of the destination file</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

for default_dir in .../etc/apps/*/default/data/ui/views/
do
    local_dir=${default_dir/\/default\///local/} # replaces the first occurrence of "/default/" with "/local/"

    for src_file in "$default_dir"*.xml
    do
        dest_file=${local_dir}${src_file##*/}

        # we'll process the local file when it's present (instead of the default one)
        [[ -e "$dest_file" ]] && src_file=$dest_file

        if line=$( awk '
            {
                ok = /version=/
                if (!ok)
                    sub( />/, "version=\"1.1\">" )
                print
                exit !ok
            }
        ' "$src_file"
        )
        then
            printf 'No change necessary to %q\n' "$src_file"
        else
            printf 'Generating %q' "$dest_file"

            { echo "$line"; cat "$src_file"; } > "$dest_file".tmp &&
            mv "$dest_file".tmp "$dest_file"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: This is real cool, thank you. If I'm reading it correctly, this won't create a new file if it sees that there's a version= in the first line. What just occurred to me is what happens if there's a file in the $dest dir w/ the same name but different contents? These are splunk dashboards that need an update, and some have already been copied over to the local dir when changes had been made. I may need to re-think the logic here, because I don't want to overwrite those in local w/ the files in default if they already exist. is there some logic that can be added to this to work through that?

Comment: Crap. In addition, see the comment replying to jetchisel. The * in the src & dest dir is a wildcard meaning that this needs to recurse in all the directories under etc/apps/. It would look like the file in etc/apps/app1/default/data/ui/views/file1.xml would be copied to etc/apps/app1/local/data/ui/views/file1.xml

Comment: You can test if there's already a corresponding file in the local dir, then modify the local one instead of the default one. For the globs, you'll have to replace `/default/` with `/local/` while looping through the files

Comment: @manderson I updated the code with a way of handling that

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use pipes and `basename`. E.g.

```
ls <DIR>/*.xml | while read FULLPATH; do 
   SRC=$(basename $FULLPATH)
   <your code>
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution/approach with `bash` and `find` and `ed` to edit the file in place, but change to something available in your system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str='version='
value=1.1
src=../etc/apps/default/data/ui/views
dest=../etc/apps/local/data/ui/views

while IFS= read -rd '' -u3 files; do
  IFS= read -r first_line < "$files"
  if [[ $first_line = *"$str"* ]]; then
    printf 'No change necessary to %s\n' "$files"
  else
    printf "Copying %s to local %s\n" "$files" "$src/${files##*/}"        
    cp -v "$files" "$dest" || exit
    printf 'Inserting %s at the first line of %s\n' "$str$value" "$dest/${files##*/}"
    printf '%s\n' '0a' "<?xml $str${value}?>" . w q | ed -s "$dest/${files##*/}"
  fi
done 3< <(find "$src" -type f -name '*.xml' -print0)
```

---

Create a dummy directories and files.

```
mkdir -vp ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/
mkdir -vp ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/
touch  ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/{foo,bar,baz,more}.xml
echo 'version="1.1"' > ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/foo.xml
```

---

Check the created directories and files.

```
tree ./etc
```

---

Output

```
./etc/
└── apps
    ├── default
    │   └── data
    │       └── ui
    │           └── views
    │               ├── bar.xml
    │               ├── baz.xml
    │               ├── foo.xml
    │               └── more.xml
    └── local
        └── data
            └── ui
                └── views

9 directories, 4 files
```

---

Check the contents of the files in the *default* directory.

```
tail -n+1 ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/*.xml
```

---

Output

```
==> ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/bar.xml <==

==> ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/baz.xml <==

==> ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/foo.xml <==
version="1.1"

==> ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/more.xml <==
```

---

Now execute your script but remove the first `.` from the path, e.g.

```
src=./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views
dest=./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views
```

---

Output

```
Copying ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/bar.xml to local ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/bar.xml
'./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/bar.xml' -> './etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/bar.xml'
Inserting version="1.1" at the first line of ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/bar.xml
Copying ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/more.xml to local ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/more.xml
'./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/more.xml' -> './etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/more.xml'
Inserting version="1.1" at the first line of ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/more.xml
Copying ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/baz.xml to local ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/baz.xml
'./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/baz.xml' -> './etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/baz.xml'
Inserting version="1.1" at the first line of ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/baz.xml
No change necessary to ./etc/apps/default/data/ui/views/foo.xml
```

---

Check the contents of directories.

```
tree ./etc
```

---

Output

```
./etc/
└── apps
    ├── default
    │   └── data
    │       └── ui
    │           └── views
    │               ├── bar.xml
    │               ├── baz.xml
    │               ├── foo.xml
    │               └── more.xml
    └── local
        └── data
            └── ui
                └── views
                    ├── bar.xml
                    ├── baz.xml
                    └── more.xml

9 directories, 7 files
```

---

Check the file contents from the *local* directory.

```
tail -n+1 ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/*.xml
```

---

Output

```
==> ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/bar.xml <==
<?xml version="1.1"?>

==> ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/baz.xml <==
<?xml version="1.1"?>

==> ./etc/apps/local/data/ui/views/more.xml <==
<?xml version="1.1"?>
```

---

The script works as intended, just make an adjustment to your needs like Changing the `ed` code from

```
printf '%s\n' '0a' "<?xml ${str}?>" . w q | ed -s
```

to your `sed` or prefererably an xml editor/parser that can be scripted like `xmlstarlet` and the likes.

---

As per the OP's comment including the `*` glob in the path and an existing file to dest should not be overwritten. The `*` does not expand on a variable assignment. An `array` is needed for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

top_dirs=(./etc/apps/*/)
dest=local/data/ui/views/
src=default/data/ui/views/

shopt -u nullglob

str='version='
value=1.1    

while IFS= read -rd '' -u3 files; do
  IFS= read -r first_line < "$files"
  ##: skip files if it is in local/data/ui/views/, don't overwrite.
    [[ -e "${files/default/local}" ]] && continue
  if [[ $first_line = *"$str"* ]]; then
    printf 'No change necessary to %s\n' "$files"
  elif [[ $first_line != *"$str"* ]]; then
    printf "Copying %s to local %s\n" "$files" "${files/default/local}"
    cp -v "$files" "${files/default/local}"
    printf 'Inserting %s at the first line of %s\n' "$str$value" "${files/default/local}"
    printf '%s\n' '0a' "<?xml $str${value}?>" . w q | ed -s "${files/default/local}"
  fi
done 3< <(find "${top_dirs[@]/%/"$src"}" -type f -name '*xml' -print0)
```

---

The above script was tested against the dummy files/directories with:

```
mkdir -vp ./etc/apps/dir{1..5}/default/data/ui/views/
mkdir -vp ./etc/apps/dir{1..5}/local/data/ui/views/
touch ./etc/apps/dir{1..5}/default/data/ui/views/{foo,bar,baz,more}.xml
echo 'version=' > ./etc/apps/dir1/default/data/ui/views/foo.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep like so:

```
grep -vril 'version="1.1"' .../etc/apps/*/default/data/ui/views/*.xml
```

It'll give you the list of files you without `version="1.1"`
Something like that may work:

```
while read file_path; do
    file_name=$(basename "$file_path")
    echo 'version="1.1"' > ./"$file_name"
    cat  "$file_path"   >> ./"$file_name"
done < <(grep -vril 'version="1.1"' .../etc/apps/*/default/data/ui/views/*.xml)
```